# How to implement a mapbox search box

Tags: javascript, python, django, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am struggling to implement a single map box search box into my project.

I have a form and an input box that I would like to show POI suggestions. So I am employing the MapBox search bar.

```
<form method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="search" name="search_query" placeholder="Enter a Location">
        <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

I have tried to copy this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/example/theming/

and my resulting code was:

```
<form method="GET">
            {% csrf_token %} 
            <script>
                const accessToken = '';
                const script = document.getElementById('search-js');
                script.onload = function() {mapboxsearch.autofill({accessToken});};
            </script>
            <input type="search" name="search_query" placeholder="Enter a Location" autocomplete="street- address" style="overflow:scroll">
            <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
```

This code did not work and I have a few issues:

1. **I do not want the mapbox search box to make my webpage scroll** and I have tried to control it with the html/css  (`style="overflow:scroll"`) but I believe I have to control the search box itself but I do not know how to do this.
2. **I want the search bar to show POIs** (such as a shop if a user types it in) and not just addresses. This solution only shows addresses and the html attribute autocomplete does not have an `autocomplete = "places"` option.